# Is it possible to use orWhereRaw more than once in a bookshelf.js query?

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am trying to create a function which would allow the user to search by multiple parameters. Here is the code.

```
async function searchUsers(searchText) {
  if(isNaN(searchText)){
    searchText = "'%" + searchText + "%'";
  } else {
    searchText = searchText;
  }

  let results = await User.query({whereRaw: ' (`firstName` LIKE ' + searchText , orWhereRaw: '`lastName` LIKE ' + searchText
    , orWhereRaw: '`username` LIKE' + searchText, orWhereRaw: '`providerId` =' + searchText + ")"}).fetchAll();

  return results.toJSON();
}
```

Now when running this function, this is what I see in my command line.

```
sql: 'select `users`.* from `users` where  (`firstName` LIKE 1 or `providerId` =1)' }
```

As you can plainly see the query is only including firstName and providerId. There is no mention of lastName or username.

How can I include all parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is using the same key twice in the same object. The second overwrites the first.

```
assert.deepEqual({ a: true }, { a: false, a: true });
```

Use a linter to prevent this kind of problem.

Solution:

```
let results = await User.query(queryBuilder => queryBuilder
  .whereRaw('`firstName` LIKE ?', searchText)
  .orWhereRaw('`lastName` LIKE ?', searchText)
  .orWhereRaw('`username` LIKE ?', searchText)
  .orWhereRaw('`providerId` = ?', searchText)
).fetchAll();
```

Although that wont produce the parentheses you want. You don't need any raw queries for what you're doing. It's pretty standard stuff.

```
let results = await User
  .where('firstName', 'like', searchText)
  .orWhere(function () {
    this.where('firstName', 'like', searchText)
      .orWhere('lastName' 'like', searchText)
      .orWhere('username', 'like', searchText)
      .orWhere('providerId', searchText)
    });
  )
).fetchAll();
```

Refer to [Knex docs](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where) for more info.